# Self iteration in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column in excel (created a sample data below) called Name that is in the format below

Name(Column Header) 
A,Y - B,X
C,Q - W,R
and list goes on and
B,X - A,Y 
W,R - C,Q 
T,U - K,M

each row has corresponding 20 other columns. I need to remove all the rows that are  present in Name column in reverse format. Such as "B,X - A,Y" and "W,R - C,Q" and all its corresponding column values but the rows "A,Y - B,X" and "C,Q - W,R" should not be deleted.

Comment: What does your data look like when you import it into R? Is it a data frame? How many column? Is `"A,Y"` one column and `"B,X"` the next or is `"A,Y - B,X"` one column? Or is it 4 columns? Please share sample data in valid R syntax.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to import the excel data in data frame. Regarding the value position, it can be anywhere in that column. Don't have a specific fixed value position. "A,Y - B,X" is one value

Comment: I'm not asking *"are you planning to put the data in R?"*, I'm asking you to share the data in a way that makes it easy for people to help you: something **we** can copy/paste into R. See [how to make a reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you need guidance - `dput()` or code to simulate the data makes it easy.

Comment: structure(list(Name = c("A,Y - B,X", "C,Q - W,R", "E,F - B,T", 
"E,T - F, B", "Q,P - P,O", "B,X - A,Y", "W,R - C,Q", "T,U - K,M"
)), .Names = "Name", class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% separate(Name, into = c("pair1", "pair2"), sep = " - ", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(p1 = pmin(pair1, pair2), p2 = pmax(pair1, pair2)) %>%
    distinct(p1, p2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    select(-pair1, -pair2, -p1, -p2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 1
#         Name
#        <chr>
# 1  A,Y - B,X
# 2  C,Q - W,R
# 3  E,F - B,T
# 4 E,T - F, B
# 5  Q,P - P,O
# 6  T,U - K,M
```

Separate the pairs, use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort them consistently, and finally deduplicate on the sorted pairs (keeping the first occurrence only).

Comment: Thanks Gregor! A quick question, will it ignore the cases where Let's say we have a rows Q,T - B,N and A,Y - N,O

Comment: Yup. Only if both pairs match a previous row will it remove the row. But don't take my word for it - add another row to your sample data and see!

Comment: Hi Gregor, I tried using the above code for my actual whole database, but it's not removing all the reversed values, just a few.

Comment: As long as the space is consistent, it shouldn't matter. Run up to each line and see that it looks to be working. If you need help debugging, share a reproducible example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I have updated the dput code in the question. For that data, i am not able to remove all the duplicates from the above code. For example- after running the code, Ut, Y - Pa, J still exists in the column. There are similar cases to this one in the final output

Comment: @Joe Well, I'm very confused about why the original didn't work. If I can't figure it out I may need to ask a question myself about it. But something about the `filter(!duplicated())` was a problem. Switching to `dplyr::distinct` seems to fix it. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strsplit function to create two new columns in your dataframe - one column of the stuff to the left of the "-" and one column for the stuff to the right. Then you just subset the dataframe to keep the rows that you want.

Comment: I need to remove the reversed duplicates rows from that column. By splitting it, I am not sure how will I identify the rows which are reversed

Comment: You can then add an index column (starting at 1, to however many rows you have). Then you can say that if a row from column B (after the hyphen) is duplicated in column A (before the hyphen), drop which ever row has the higher index value.